# How do I send mail from linux command line so it appears as HTML to recipient?

Tags: linux, email, html

I've tried emailing a normal web page using something like:

> `mail -s "Test Email" blah@blah.com < webpage.htm`

However, the recipient sees the raw HTML tags in the email and none of my careful formatting. Am using RedHat Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell the MUA that the content contains HTML. Traditionally this is done using MIME. Try adding the following header lines to your message:

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
```

You may need to add a Content-Transfer-Encoding header as well. The [Wikipedia page on MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) has more details, including links to relevant RFCs.

Update: This worked fine when piped into `sendmail -t`:

```
From: me@example.org
To: me@gmail.com
Subject: MIME Test
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
<body>
This is a test.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I have content type `application/xhtml+xml` it comes as an attachment. Do You think it can be fixed?

Comment: Another question: if I have inline images in html file -- how do I keep them with this method (`sendmail -t`)?

Comment: As to inline images: I [found a solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4313697/788700) -- but gmail won't load the images (yahoo do).

Answer (score 2):

Solucion a envio html

```
mail -a 'MIME-Version: 1.0' -a 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' -a 'X-AUTOR: Ing. Gareca' -s 'MTA STATUS: mail queue' rgareca@hotmail.com  -- -f seincotel@seincotel.com  < /tmp/eximrep.html
```

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible with `mail` afaik. But [here](http://www.liamdelahunty.com/tips/linux_send_html_email_from_command_line.php) is a short how-to with sendmail.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible with mail:

```
mail -a 'Content-type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"' foo@bar.com < /file.html
```

Comment: I get an error :

`Content-type: text/html; charset="us-ascii": No such file or directory.`

From mail --help, I get that the -a option is for passing FILE.

Answer (score 0):

Email messages, like web pages, have their content type specified in the headers. 'mail' seems to predate this and doesn't send any, and so all MUAs fall back to displaying the message as text/plain.

If you want to specify all headers manually, call `sendmail recipient@example.com` and pass everything to it.

*`<subjective>`* But remember that while HTML emails are disliked by some people (including me), receiving HTML emails *without an alternate text/plain part* is **really annoying**. So, unless you're absolutely sure the recipient can see HTML messages fine, it would be better to send a multipart message with a plain-text part as an alternative. *`</subjective>`*

Comment: SMTP (STD 11/RFC 823, 1982) does in fact predate MIME (RFC 2045, 1996) and all of its HTML-enabled goodness. It was formed from buffalo hides at the dawn of the Internet.

Comment: Gerald: I meant the `mailx` MUA (which for some reason I feel is even older), not email itself.

Comment: According to the OS X mail(1) page, "A mail command appeared in Version 1 AT&T UNIX." Ubuntu says it was Version 3 AT&T UNIX. Either way it appears to have shown up around 1971 or 1973.

Answer (score 0):

`uuencode webpage.html webpage.html | mail -s "subject" email@address`